# Filtering a query with a has_many relationship with GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Having an issue with a super simple Gorm query on a simple many_to_many relationship, I have 3 tables in a MYSQL DB modelled like so:

```
type Product struct {
    ID          uint         `gorm:"unique"  json:"id"`
    Name        string       `gorm:"name"  json:"name"`
    Ingredients []Ingredient `gorm:"many2many:product_ingredients;"  json:"ingredients"`
}

type Ingredient struct {
    ID   uint   `gorm:"unique" json:"id"`
    Name string `gorm:"name" json:"name"`
}
```

(And a joining table)

I want a query which fetches all products where the ingredient is included in a certain product:

I can get general queries with all data doing this:

```
db.Debug().Preload("Ingredients").Limit(limit).Offset(offset).Find(&products)
```

But trying to do something like this

```
db.Debug().Preload("Ingredients").Limit(limit).Offset(offset).Where(Ingredient{Name: "Chicken"}).Find(&products)
```

Gives me
Error 1054: Unknown column 'ingredients.name' in 'where clause'

I'm expecting to only return products that have chicken as an ingredient.

Anyone able to help?

This should be fairly simple but I can't find any use cases like this and the docs are quite confusing.